# What is the simplest way to deploy a Captive Portal?

Tags: linux, mac-osx, wifi, captive-portal

How do I setup in the simplest of ways a Captive Portal? One that is possible on a setup of 1 wireless router and 2 computers. No billing, only authentication.

Also, is it possible to do with Mac OS X machines?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [pfsense](http://www.pfsense.org) Firewall distribution. It features captive portal and can even be installed on small appliances, like the [Alix](http://www.pcengines.ch) board (they have some with Wifi support).